# Find out memory leak?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, abaddressbook

i am new on iphone apps.Now this is my first app,app is installed but not run?
I write this code it shows memory leak.please find out.Thanks in advance.

```
ABRecordRef ref = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(all, i);

CFStringRef *firstName = (CFStringRef *)ABRecordCopyValue(ref, kABPersonFirstNameProperty);
NSLog(@"Name %@", firstName);
contact.strFirstName = (NSString*)firstName;

CFStringRef *lastName = (CFStringRef *)ABRecordCopyValue(ref, kABPersonLastNameProperty);
NSLog(@"Name %@", lastName);
contact.strLastName = (NSString*)lastName;
contact.contactName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",(NSString *)firstName,lastName];
NSLog(@"Name %@", contact.contactName);

ABMutableMultiValueRef phoneNumbers = ABRecordCopyValue(ref, kABPersonPhoneProperty);
for(CFIndex j = 0; j < ABMultiValueGetCount(phoneNumbers); j++)
{
    CFStringRef phoneNumberRef = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phoneNumbers, j);

    NSString *phoneNumber = (NSString *) phoneNumberRef;
    contact.strMobileNo = phoneNumber;
    NSLog(@"phoneNO is %@", phoneNumber);

    CFRelease(phoneNumberRef);

}       

ABMultiValueRef emails = ABRecordCopyValue(ref, kABPersonEmailProperty);
for(CFIndex k = 0; k < ABMultiValueGetCount(emails); k++)
{
    CFStringRef emailRef = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(emails, k);
    NSString *mailid = (NSString *) emailRef;
    contact.strMail = mailid;
    NSLog(@"Email is %@", mailid);

    CFRelease(emailRef);

}

CFRelease(emails);
CFRelease(phoneNumbers);
```

Comment: Why not use the memory leak finder from xcode?

Comment: i used that but i didn't got bcz i m new on this tech

Answer (score 2):

You are using `ABRecordCopyValue` on firstName and lastName which means you need to `CFRelease` those as well.

Comment: hai, i release those two firstName and lastName app was crash......so please help me.......

Comment: You need to add `CFRelease` after the line `NSLog(@"Name %@", contact.contactName);` where were you releasing it?

Answer (score 1):

CFRelease is a way to go (as @Joe and @jamapag already answered).. I would just like to add that XCode has few nice features like cmd + shift + a gives u a static memory analyser.. And you can also use run -> run w/ performance tools and then use allocations or leaks to analyse our memory management dynamically.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions.i will check it once

Answer (score 0):

You need to add:

```
CFRelease(firstName);
CFRelease(lastName);
```

Comment: hai, i release those two firstName and lastName app was crash......so please help me.......